# Why FieldSeparators is printing a lot of quotation marks instead of just spaces?

Tags: export, list-manipulation

In the following code `"FieldSeparators"->" "` prints a lot of quotation marks in the output file, instead of just spaces. What's wrong with it?

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
s = 30; sy = s;
nmin = 0; nmax = 3; xmin = 0; xmax = 3;

out = Flatten[
        Table[{N[n] // ToString[PaddedForm[#, {6, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}]] &,
               N[x] // ToString[PaddedForm[#, {6, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}]] &, 
               N[BesselJ[n, 3 x]] /. {
                  Indeterminate -> "nan", ComplexInfinity -> "nan", Infinity -> "inf"} //
                  ToString[ PaddedForm[#, {6, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}]] &},
              {n, nmin, nmax, (nmax - nmin)/(s - 1)}, 
              {x, xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/(sy - 1)}], 1];

$file = OpenWrite["bessel.txt"]; 

Export[$file, out[[1 ;; s]], "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "];

For[ i = 2, i <= s, i++, 
     WriteString[$file, "\n\n"] 

     Export[$file, out[[1 + (i - 1)*s ;; i*s]], "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "]]

Close[$file];
```

Comment: A double-space seems to work OK. Odd...

Comment: @cormullion not fore me :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is a bug, since any other characters apart from space work as expected.
By thye way, in your input some semicolons are missing, after WriteString and before Close.

What you might to is to export with Tab separation (either "FieldSeparators" -> "\t" or no options, since it should be the default) and then convert to spaces with:

```
Export["bessel.txt",
    StringReplace[
        Import["bessel.txt", "Text"],
        "\t" -> " "
    ],
    "Text"
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest simplifying your code by generating the output table as a single string, completely formated in the way you want it appear in your text file. Then you can bypass fussing with the file writing. The modifications that need to be made to your code are small.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
s = 30; sy = s;
nmin = 0; nmax = 3; xmin = 0; xmax = 3;
i = 0;
out = 
  StringJoin @@ 
    Flatten @
      Table[{
        N[n] // ToString[PaddedForm[#, {6, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}]] &,
        N[x] // ToString[PaddedForm[#, {7, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}]] &,
        N[BesselJ[n, 3 x]] /. 
          {Indeterminate -> "nan", ComplexInfinity -> "nan", Infinity -> "inf"} // 
            ToString[PaddedForm[#, {7, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}]] &,
        If[Mod[++i, s] == 0, "\n\n", "\n"]},
     {n, nmin, nmax, (nmax - nmin)/(s - 1)}, 
     {x, xmin, xmax, (xmax - xmin)/(sy - 1)}];
Export["bessel.txt", out]
```

The resulting file will look like this:

> ```
>  0.      0.       1.     
>  0.      0.10345  0.97607
>  0.      0.2069   0.90598
>  0.      0.31034  0.79476
> ...
>  0.      2.89655 -0.00973
>  0.      3.      -0.09033
>
>  0.10345 0.       0.     
>  0.10345 0.10345  0.84929
>  0.10345 0.2069   0.8531 
>  0.10345 0.31034  0.79121
> ...
> ```

Comment: I feel awkward because I appreciate your solution very much, but I'm going to accept @user8074's answer since it preserves the original table. Thank you very much anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There's something going on I don't understand - here's a simpler example:

```
pad[n_] := ToString[
  PaddedForm[n, {6, 5}, NumberPadding -> {" ", " "}]];
out = Table[pad@N[BesselJ[n, n x]] , {n, 1, 5}, {x, 1, 5}]
```

[image: table output]

```
ExportString[out, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> " "] (* one space *)
```

[image: export 1]

```
ExportString[out, "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> "  "] (* two spaces *)
```

[image: export 2]

Answer (score 0):

Does using "TSV" file format suit your needs? Further, `ShowStringCharacters->False` can be used to suppress the string characters in output. This did not seem to work consistentl with "FieldSeparator" option for Table.

Modified end of your code:

```
$file = OpenWrite["bessel.txt"];

Export[$file, out[[1 ;; s]], "TSV", ShowStringCharacters -> False];

For[i = 2, i <= s, i++, 
 WriteString[$file, "\n\n"] Export[$file, out[[1 + (i - 1)*s ;; i*s]],
    "TSV", ShowStringCharacters -> False]]

Close[$file];
```

Comment: It seems to me that this way I get the same result as without `FieldSeparators` or as with `"FieldSeparators"->"\t"`

Comment: @Luigi Sorry if this was unhelpful. I tried the code and got a tab separated  table without string characters. I could  not ShowStringCharacters->False to suppress the string characters with other attempts.